# How do I reference data in an HABTM table without a model in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

So I recently created an HABTM relationship between two models (project & user).

Before, I had a user_id column in my project table - that would act like a foreign key. Now there is an entire table that does that.

But how do I reference projects that have a specific user_id & project_id ?

For instance, I used to have a section of my view that looked like this:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :project_id %><br />
        <%= collection_select(:stage, :project_id, Project.where(:user_id => current_user), :id, :name) %>
        <br />
    </div>
```

But how do I now pull the same info from the db, with no model for the HABTM table? The new table is called 'projects_users'.

My projects model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101125223049
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  notified    :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :stages, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments

  #before_validation { |project| project.user = Authorization.current_user unless project.user }

end
```

My User Model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20101124095341
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)     default(""), not null
#  password_salt        :string(255)     default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer         default(0)
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  username             :string(255)
#  role                 :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, and :lockable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :stages
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end  
end
```

As an aside...how do I edit that table from the rails console - without a model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but `Project.where(:user_id => current_user)` should become `current_user.projects`

And to add user with id 1 to project with id 3 you'd do

```
Project.find(3).users << User.find(1)
```

Is this what you've been trying to do ?

Comment: changing to current_user.projects worked. Thnx. As for the second part, is that supposed to b at the console ? If so, doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you should use the second part in the console. It should work. Are you sure you have instances with the ids you're using? Try this instead: Project.first.users << User.first

Comment: That worked. Where can I read up more about that ? For instance, how can I view all entries in the projects_users table from the console ?

Comment: Check this out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html If you want to view all entries in the projects_users table from the console, I think you'll need to use an association join model (as explained in the link above). I don't know how else to do it in the console. Otherwise, my only suggestion would be to look directly in the DB table.

Comment: Thank you. That link to the API is EXACTLY what I was looking for. The guides don't really give me ALL the details. But this does. Thanks much.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will work for you. Basically you're grabbing all the projects for a certain user and then narrowing it down by project_id.

```
user_id = 3 #example
project_id = 2 #example
User.find(user_id).projects.find(project_id)
```

If you want to manually edit the join table you can use the relationships directly.

```
project = Project.create
user = User.first

#add a new row to the join table for the user_id,project_id
user.projects << project 

#delete all records from the join table referencing this user.
user.projects = []
```

Comment: When I run the `User.find(user_id).projects.find(project_id)` this is the error message I get: `undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<#<Class:0x00000101e46478>:0x00000101e3e8e0>`

Comment: Yeah, user_id is supposed to be a variable holding the user_id that you want. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The problem is that I need it to auto detect the current user + current project.

Answer (score 0):

This RailsCasts helped me a lot - it will answer your questions. http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association